# How to create a dynamic formset from form in Django/AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, django-forms

I'm working on a page which contains two forms. One of this forms is regular one - name, description, notes etc. The second one is two dropdown menus - `Language` and `Level` where the `Level` is chained with `Language` using `AJAX`.

I want to make this form appears on the page as many times as `user` wants. So ifthey fill `Language` and `Level`, there appears new `Language` and `Level` form below the old one.

The problem is that if the form is chained, I have to identify each `Language` and `Level` separately so I can't just copy the `form` this in repeat. (Maybe I can but I can't figure it out since I'm new in AJAX).

This is a `create job` django/html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% load static %}
{% block head %}
    <script src="{% static  "js/main.js" %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
            {{ language_form }}
            <button value="Update" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

This is the JQuery:

```
 $(document).on('change','#id_language',function(){
     language_id = $(this).val();
     request_url = '/get-highest-level/'+language_id+'/';
     $.ajax({
         url:request_url,
         success: function(data){
             var select = $('#id_level');
             select.empty();
             $.each(data, function (key,value) {
                 $('select[name="level"]').append('<option value="'+ key + '">'+value + '</option>');
             });
             return false;
         }
     })
});
```

And a simple view:

```
@login_required
def create_order(request):
    language_form = LanguageLevelForm(request.POST or None)
    return render(request,'auth/jobs/create-job-test.html',context={'language_form':language_form})
```

I know that it should be possible to use `FormSet` but I can't figure out how to make it work with the `JQuery`.
[image: This is how the formset looks like in HTML]

Answer (score 1):

To refresh select options, you don't have to identify them.
If the language form is wrapped with div or something, there's only one closest level select for a language select.

```
$(document).on('change','select.language',function(){ // use class, not id
     language_id = $(this).val();
     request_url = '/get-highest-level/'+language_id+'/';
     var language = $(this);
     $.ajax({
         url:request_url,
         success: function(data){
             //find closest select with class "level"
             var select = language.closest('select.level'); 
             select.empty();
             $.each(data, function (key,value) {
                 // use select found above.
                 select.append('<option value="'+ key + '">'+value + '</option>');
             });
             return false;
         }
     })
});
```

Similarly, you can change attributes of them without identifying.

```
$('select.language').each(function(index){
    $(this).attr('name', 'language' + index);
});
```

**EDIT :** With your sample HTML, try this..

```
$(document).on('change','select[id$="language"]',function(){ // id ends with 'language'
     language_id = $(this).val();
     request_url = '/get-highest-level/'+language_id+'/';
     var level_select_id = $(this).attr('id').replace('language', 'level'); // tricky..
     $.ajax({
         url:request_url,
         success: function(data){
             var select = $('#' + level_select_id); // use id string found above
             select.empty();
             $.each(data, function (key,value) {
                 select.append('<option value="'+ key + '">'+value + '</option>');
             });
             return false;
         }
     })
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried it with single form and with formset too but it don't work. Problably because there is no class. I've added an html of formset at the bottom of my question

Comment: Oh, this works for chained forms, thank you. But I still didn't figure out how to make it adding after filling. First form is filled -> Second form appears etc.